# http calls to json-server refreshes my page

Tags: angular, json-server

I have an Angular 11 app. I am running it via npm serve on the default port 4200. I am also running json-server on port 3000. I have created a simple form and on submit of that form, using httpClient I am posting my request.

this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/movie', newMovieObj).subscribe(res => console.log(res);

The new movie is added but my page is refreshed. Upon looking at the response headers there is location header which points to "http://localhost:3000/{newMovieId}". I assuming this is causing the refresh. How do I stop this refresh?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know I'm late but I had the identical problem until just now and came across this post.

The problem is that when a post is done, an entry is made in the db.json of the json server. Angular recognizes this as a change and restarts the application.

The solution is simply to have the db.json folder outside the sry folder